# mvc3 view viewdata and viewbag is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I can't seem to pass any data via the ViewBag or ViewData to the View. It just keeps coming back with null.

ViewResult code:

```
    public ViewResult EditProduct(Guid id)
    {
        var product = _repository.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);

        ViewData["Categories"] = _repository.Categories;
        ViewData["CategoryList"] = _repository.Categories.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.ID.ToString(), Selected = product.ID == x.ID });
        ViewBag.Test = "Hello";

        return View(product);
    }
```

and this is the razor code:

```
@model NightingalecrossMVC.Domain.Entities.Product
@{
    var test = ViewData.Eval("CategoryList");

    var test2 = ViewBag.Test;

    ViewBag.Title = "Edit Treatment";

    AjaxOptions ajaxOpts = new AjaxOptions
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "saveData",
        HttpMethod = "Post",
        LoadingElementId = "loader"
    };
}
```

Why is this happening? It works fine on any other view?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for getting null values is because I had this:

```
    public ViewResult CreateProduct()
    {
        return View("EditProduct", new Product());
    }
```

It needed to be this:

```
    public ViewResult CreateProduct()
    {
        ViewBag.CategoryList = _repository.Categories.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.ID.ToString() });
        return View("EditProduct", new Product());
    }
```

EDIT

Actually you can't make a selectlistitem list like that because of the ToString() method in the LINQ, it needs to be elongated with {} instead of new SelectListItem to make a proper function out of it. But then this will decrease readability. So the best solution is to make a function that returns IEnumerable then you can make a SelectList.

There has been some controversy about using SelectList and that DropDownList doesn't support that overload. However SelectList does implement IEnumerable so shouldn't therefore support SelectList.

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution. When in doubt you can always set a dummy value- e.g. a string - and pass this through to determine whether the problem exists in your controller or your razor view. You could also set a break-point on the controller with a watch on the variable you're trying to debug, then use f10 to step through line-by-line. I also realised that you can add break-points in Razor view the other day. You may also be better off using a ViewModel rather than ViewData in this context - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvc3fundamentals_topic7.aspx.

Comment: I tried with a ViewModel, and it didn't work that well, I think for this problem there is no scalability so a ViewModel would be overkill. The issue with the break point is that I didn't know CreateProduct was calling the EditProduct so when I put break point in EditProduct nothing was hit. But in the then end when I started breaking at certain points and figured where the code was being executed I soon found the true root of the problem.

Comment: Sure, but your ViewModel could just be a property for the entity, e.g. `public EntityType YourEntity { get; set;};` and other properties in your ViewModel. Then in your repository/service, have a method like 'GetEntityEditViewModelID' which creates and empty instance of the ViewModel, then does the exact same thing as your ViewBag (but populates this against the ViewModel instead). The additional computing cost of this would be very minimal, you'll be to work with a consistent ViewModel between the GET and the POST, and you'll end up with less repository code up your controller.

Comment: Also, I've just remembered Glimpse: http://getglimpse.com/. This could potentially have helped in your situation where you wanted to find out which controller was being executed http://getglimpse.com/Help/Plugin/Execution, and also how the data is being bound http://getglimpse.com/Help/Plugin/Binding

Comment: @AaronNewton Please look at this new question that I have answered, shows me using the ViewModel instead of the ViewData or ViewBag [Stack Overflow ViewModel Usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950479/mvc-3-dropdownfor-and-viewmodel-not-working)

Comment: Have a look at Dead.Rabbit's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/13950855/201648) as I suspect this is your problem. I've added some information in a comment for you.